# React Native Parse LiveQuery error on socket

Tags: sockets, parse-platform, react-native, livequery

I am having trouble connecting to the LiveQuery server that I setup on the server side of my React Native project. I followed the instructions on the site verbatim, but can only manage to get 'error on socket' when I connect with numerous attempts by the server to reconnect.

Here is my server setup:

```
liveQuery: {
        classNames: ['BekonRequest'],
    } 
var port = 1337;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port); }); 
    var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(server); 

server.listen(port, function() {
console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port);
});  

var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(server);
```

And my client side code:

```
let requestQuery = new Parse.Query('BekonRequest');
    requestQuery.equalTo("username", "broncos@nfl.com");
    let subscription = requestQuery.subscribe();

    subscription.on('create', (requests) => {
        console.log(requests);
    });
```

Can anyone see why I am not able to connect successfully?

Comment: Any update on this ?